# For threaded messaging, not sure how to generate unique thread_id ONLY WHEN a thread_id is not specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, messaging

I expect that this is a rather common problem seeing as a lot of sites use threaded messaging, but I haven't been able to find anything on the internets.

Basically the way I envision this working is I have a column called thread_id in my messages table.  The column is not unique, because obviously a lot of messages will be sharing the same thread.  What I'd like to see happen is when I insert a new message, if I specify a thread_id, it uses it as expected, but if I don't, it uses the next available thread_id by auto incrementing the highest value.

So if I have a series of messages with thread ids: 1,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,4,2,5,3,3,3,4 and then I insert a row without an id, it would use the id 6.

Is this possible?  If not, how do most people accomplish threaded messaging?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish, but if you just need an incrementing value, then I could just use a sequencer...  that's kind of what they are for.  Again, might be a dumb suggestion, but it sort of sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is create a wrapper model:

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end
```

to act as the parent of your messages. That way, if you know which thread you want to add a message to you can just call `@thread.messages.create!(params[:message])`. If want to add a message to a new thread, you can just create a new thread and add the message in the same way. You won't have to worry about assigning an incremented thread_id to the message, as the Thread model will automatically auto-increment the id of the new thread and assign it to the message.

This method also allows you keep track of info about the thread, like when the thread was created by having a "created_at" column, if that at all interests you.